# Regex (Python) - Way around a quantifier with a Look-Behind?

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of many elements (all strings but unfortunately lots of whitespace too), here's two elements as an example:

```
sample_string = '8000KE60803F6                ST FULL-DEPTH TEETH            1 EA           36,56          36,56    2,00           0,73           37,29' ,'8522-3770                    CONTACT            2 EA          311,45         622,90    2,00          12,46          635,36'
my_list = list(sample_string)
```

I wish to use regex to extract the first number/letter sequence (in the case of the above, that's 8000KE60803F6  and 8522-3770)
I then wish to extract the next alpha sequence (in the case of the above, that's 'ST FULL-DEPTH TEETH' and 'CONTACT')
Lastly I wish to extract the numeric value that follows the EA (in the case of the above, that's 36,56 and 311,45)

I have tried the following

```
for item in my_list:
    line=re.search(r'([A-Z0-9]*)(\s*)((?<=EA\s)[\d,]*)', item)
    if line:
        PN = line.group(1)
        Name = line.group(2)
        Price = line.group(3)
    print(PN)
    print(Name)
    print(Price)
```

The above outputs

EA

EA

However, I am seeking the following output:

PN: 8000KE60803F6 and 8522-3770

Name: ST FULL-DEPTH TEETH and CONTACT

Price: 36,56 and 311,45

And in reality, need to iterate through a large list.

I have also tried lookarounds, but get the common error when a quantifier is used with them?

Comment: Group 2 is just `(\s*)`. How do you expect that to capture the name?

Comment: Is PN always at the beginning? You should anchor it with `^` to prevent matching later, or use `re.match()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
^(?P<PN>\S+)\s+(?P<Name>.*?)\s+\d+\s+EA\s+(?P<Price>\d[\d,]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TvYmV7/1/). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?P<PN>\S+)` - Group `PN`: one or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?P<Name>.*?)` - Group `Name`: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `\s+\d+\s+`  - one or more digits enclosed with one or more whitespaces
- `EA` - an `EA` string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?P<Price>\d[\d,]*)` - Group `Price`: a digit and then any zero or more digits or commas.

In Python, you can use it like

```py
import re
rx = re.compile(r'^(?P<PN>\S+)\s+(?P<Name>.*?)\s+\d+\s+EA\s+(?P<Price>\d[\d,]*)')
l = ['8000KE60803F6                ST FULL-DEPTH TEETH            1 EA           36,56          36,56    2,00           0,73           37,29',
'8522-3770                    CONTACT            2 EA          311,45         622,90    2,00          12,46          635,36']
for el in l:
    m = rx.match(el)
    if m:
        print(m.groupdict())
# => {'PN': '8000KE60803F6', 'Name': 'ST FULL-DEPTH TEETH', 'Price': '36,56'}
#    {'PN': '8522-3770', 'Name': 'CONTACT', 'Price': '311,45'}
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/zahX5E).

Comment: thanks Wiktor - I am having trouble working with the output. It is only returning None Type. I cannot assign the output to anything so I can use later?

Comment: @Prolle Do you check if there is a match? See `if m:` in my code.

Comment: yes @Wiktor, I do get matches, your code works as shown in your sample above. Many thanks for that, however, I cannot 'use' these matches later? I have tried to assign a variable name to the dictionaries but it does not work

Comment: @Prolle [Example](https://ideone.com/O1Y21F): `results = [rx.match(el).groupdict() for el in l if rx.match(el)]`. If you do not like the idea of called `re.match` twice, use [this approach](https://ideone.com/BrAUV9).

Comment: many thanks for that, I was trying list comprehension, but was stuck. This works great! Gentleman.

Answer (score 2):

You may use this regex with 3 captured groups:

```sh
(?P<PN>[A-Z\d-]+)\s+(?P<Name>[A-Z]+(?:[\s-]+[A-Z]+)*)\s+[^,]+?EA\s+(?P<Price>\d+(?:,\d+)*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Lm4au2/1)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good place to use regex groups:

```py
pattern = re.compile(r"^(?P<PN>[\w]+)\s*(?P<name>\w*(\w* )+)\s*\d+\s*EA\s*(?P<price>[\d,]+)")
```

Notice how each group is separated by arbitrarily many spaces (`\s*`), and how we name each group (`?P<...>`).

Then extracting each component is easy:

```py
for string in my_list:
    groups = pattern.match(string).groupdict()
    print(groups["PN"])
    print(groups["name"])
    print(groups["price"])
```